# How do i tell Traefik to expose a service using a different port?

Tags: docker, traefik

Based on this (https://github.com/r9r-dev/portaefik) I've set up portainer with traefik in front of it. Works great and I'm hosting several other things behind portainer and traefik with it.

I would however like for the portainer admin interface to not be accessible on the regular 80/443 ports but instead a separate port (like 9443) so I can IP filter that port in my firewall and block anyone except me from accessing it at all.

So how do I tell traefik to expose portainer on another port but keep serving other things on 80/443?

All my attempts so far have failed and either broken traefik or portainer.

This is what my current docker-compose looks like.

```
version: "3"

#https://github.com/r9r-dev/portaefik

    services:
      proxy:
        image: traefik:v3.0
        container_name: "traefik"
        networks:
          - traefik
        ports:
          - "80:80" # HTTP
          - "443:443" # HTTPS
        volumes:
          - ./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt
          - ./users.u:/users/users.u
          - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
        restart: always
        command:
          #- "--log.level=DEBUG"
          # Docker configuration
          - "--providers.docker=true"
          - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
          - "--providers.docker.network=traefik"
          # Configure entrypoint
          - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
          - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
          # SSL configuration
          - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencryptresolver.acme.httpchallenge=true"
          - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencryptresolver.acme.httpchallenge.entrypoint=web"
          #- "--certificatesresolvers.letsencryptresolver.acme.caserver=https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
          - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencryptresolver.acme.email=none@none.com"
          - "--certificatesresolvers.letsencryptresolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
          # Global HTTP -> HTTPS
          - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.to=websecure"
          - "--entrypoints.web.http.redirections.entryPoint.scheme=https"
          # Enable dashboard
          - "--api.dashboard=true"
        labels:
          - "traefik.enable=true"
          - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.entrypoints=websecure"
          - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.tls.certresolver=letsencryptresolver"
          - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.service=api@internal"
          - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.middlewares=dashboard-auth"
          - "traefik.http.middlewares.dashboard-auth.basicauth.usersfile=/users/users.u"
          - "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.rule=Host(`traefik.mydomain.se`)"
          - "traefik.http.services.dashboard.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"
    
      portainer:
        image: portainer/portainer-ce
        container_name: "portainer"
        networks:
          - traefik
        labels:
          - "traefik.enable=true"
          - "traefik.http.services.portainer.loadbalancer.server.port=9000"
          - "traefik.http.routers.portainer.rule=Host(`portainer.mydomain.se`)"
          - "traefik.http.routers.portainer.entrypoints=websecure"
          - "traefik.http.routers.portainer.tls.certresolver=letsencryptresolver"
        volumes:
          - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
          - /mnt/Storage1/docker-data/portainer:/data
        restart: always
    
    networks:
      traefik:
        external:
          name: traefik
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

Added new exposed ports to the traefik part of compose file

```
ports:
  - "80:80" # HTTP
  - "443:443" # HTTPS
  - "9443:9443" # PORTAINER  <---
  - "8080:8080" # TRAEFIK    <---
```

Added new entrypoints named **traefik** and **portainer**:

```
  - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
  - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
  - "--entrypoints.traefik.address=:8080"   <---
  - "--entrypoints.portainer.address=:9443" <---
```

Changed entrypoint for traefik dashboard and portainer.

```
- "traefik.http.routers.dashboard.entrypoints=traefik"
- "traefik.http.routers.portainer.entrypoints=portainer"
```

Now I can IP filter those and dare use this thing for production :)